# Iterate through pandas dataframe and replacing entires

Tags: python, pandas

I need to iterate through the `'Grade'` column of this dataframe and replace entries are `"1"`, `"2"`, or `"K"` with `"1/2"` and `"3"` or `"4"` with `"3/4"`

```
for i in kids_df:
    if kids_df['G'] == 1 or 2:
        kids_df['G'] = kids_df['Grade'].replace('1/2')
```

Here's the DF:

```
Name    M/F Grade   Size    Notes
0   Peter Parker    M   2   YM  Baughman
1   Tony Stark  M   1   YL  Baughman
2   Steve Rogers    M   K   YM  Baughman
3   Donald Blake    M   2   YM  Baughman
4   Bruce Banner    M   3   YM  Baughman
```

Result I'm looking for:

```
Name    M/F Grade   Size    Notes
0   Peter Parker    M   1/2 YM  Baughman
1   Tony Stark  M   1/2 YL  Baughman
2   Steve Rogers    M   1/2 YM  Baughman
3   Donald Blake    M   1/2 YM  Baughman
4   Bruce Banner    M   3/4 YM  Baughman
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `np.where`:

```
df['Grade'] = np.where(df['Grade'].isin(['1', '2', 'K']), '1/2', '3/4')
print(df)
```

Or use a double `str.replace`:

```
df['Grade'] = df['Grade'].str.replace('1|2|K', '1/2').str.replace('3|4', '3/4')
print(df)
```

Or use a `replace` with a dictionary:

```
df['Grade'] = df['Grade'].replace({'1|2|K': '1/2', '3|4': '3/4'}, regex=True)
print(df)
```

They all output:

```
           Name M/F Grade Size     Notes
0  Peter Parker   M   1/2   YM  Baughman
1    Tony Stark   M   1/2   YL  Baughman
2  Steve Rogers   M   1/2   YM  Baughman
3  Donald Blake   M   1/2   YM  Baughman
4  Bruce Banner   M   3/4   YM  Baughman
```

Comment: @rafaelc I know i added another solution

Comment: This is great. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

We can just do `replace`

```
kids_df['G']=kids_df['G'].replace({1:'1/2',2:'1/2',3:'3/4',4:'3/4'})
```